# Read data from unknown file name into an array?

Tags: shell, array, read

Question:

file name: `Celebs`
inside the file:

```
Beyonce
Brittney
Kevin
George
```

And I have to create code using the `read` and `while` commands. Here is what I have so far, but I think it's incorrect since it won't run in my shell script.

I was also told that the file name will not always be `Names` and I don't know how to input any random file into the code. I also have to use the unknown file name, with the names of the people inside the file, create an array and have it printed out in the terminal.

So I also need to print it out.

```
    list= find -name "Celebs" -type f #if its an unknown file name this method won't work
    start=0 #position of the empty array
    declare -a People
    while read -r line
      do
   People[$start]=$line #lines read to be stored in the array
    ((start++))
  done<$list
```

Comment: What shell are you using? What is `People()` supposed to do? Did you even try running it once and looking at the error messages? Did none of them help you?

Comment: People is an empty array that I created, it was suppose to store the names of the people in Celebs

Comment: Have you read anything at all about the language (whatever that is, you still haven't told us) you are trying to use? What makes you think that `People()` is the right syntax to use for creating an empty array? Hint: you are using the correct syntax 3 lines further down. I ask you again: did you not see *any* of the error messages this script would produce? Weren't any of them helpful? Did none suggest a syntax error perhaps?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error messages or nothing like that.

Comment: Then you didn't run it. Please try running it. You will see some useful error messages. Now, for the third time: what language is this supposed to be? What shell?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i didn't realized you asked that,
I've been using it on terminal, shell script Linux~

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

1. This is a `bash` script.
2. Data is being read on standard input.
3. Each line of input is to be stored in an array, then displayed once all input has been read.

Taking the data from standard input gets rid of the problem of not knowing where the data is originally stored.  It leaves the user of the script free to pipe in the data from a command or to simply redirect the input from a file.

Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 'names' is an array, empty from the start
declare -a names=()

while read name; do
    # Append the name to the end of the array
    names+=( "$name" )
done

# Output all names with each being prepended by "Name: "
printf 'Name: %s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Since we're reading names, I chose to *not* use the `-r` switch with `read`.  There are no names that I know of that contains a backslash...

We may append values to our array using the `+=` operator.

There's no need for a loop to do the output as `printf` will "loop" over its input and apply its formatting to each element of the array, so to speak<sup>1</sup>.

Testing it with the data from the question:

```
bash-4.4$ bash script <testdata
Name: Beyonce
Name: Brittney
Name: Kevin
Name: George
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>`printf` doesn't know about arrays, but it will use each line of input that it gets and format it according to the formatting string.  The variable expansion `${names[@]}` will result in several lines of input for `printf`.</sub>

Comment: In `bash`, when `declare` is called in the global context, it doesn't wipe the previous value (here there might be a `$names` variable in the environment). Issue a `unset -v` beforehand (preferable if the variable might have been declared of another type like associative array before), or use `declare -a a=()` (or use different shell like `zsh`)

Comment: In `bash`, one can use just one `readarray -t names` invocation (no need for `while read` loop). `while read var`, as opposed to `while IFS= read -r var` has a very special meaning though so would give different results from the `readarray` approach if the input contained backslashes or lines with leading or trailing space or tab characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the first note. I looked at `readarray` but decided against using it since 1) the Q stated "`read` in `while` loop" explicitly, and 2) I don't fully know how it works and what caveats comes with it.